# comparing attributes (in controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This seems like it is the simplest thing ever, but it cost me two hours of searching and trying stuff, so please give me a quick answer.

I am basically following railstutorial for an application, just that I have a field privileges (integer) instead of admin (boolean).

Now I'm trying to implement an admin? function that returns (privileges > 0).

I tried the following (and many other versions) in app/models/user.rb:

```
  # is user admin ?
  def admin?
    0 < self.privileges
  end
```

Obviously that doesn't work. Also tried putting it in app/controllers/users_controller.rb. Please help.

Comment: Obviously that doesn't work - not that obvious for me. What's wrong with it? Edit; are you getting `comparison of Fixnum with nil failed`?

Comment: Yes. regardless of how I write it (Users.privileges, @user[:privileges], etc.)
Also obvious only in the sense of there wouldn't be a question here if it worked.

Comment: Ok, normally if sth doesn't work you should tell how it doesn't work - it would make helping you easier. :) If you're getting an error message adding it to the question is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def admin?
  !!privileges && 0 < privileges
end
```

or

```
def admin?
  0 < privileges.to_i
end
```

Another options would be to set a default 0 to the column.

Comment: privileges.to_i worked. 
the column (in the database) is set to integer, why would I need to .to_i it ?

Comment: @xyious - integer column can return two things, integer or `nil`. You can't compare nil with a number and `nil.to_i` returns 0.

Comment: Can I somehow prevent the column from returning nil (like mysql allow_null) ? If so, would that change my problem ?

Comment: If you do that than your original code will work. To do so you need to create a migration: change_column :users, :privileges, :integer, default: 0, null: false